# Почему не появляется окно (window)?

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, masm32, masm

Почему у меня не появляется окно? Вроде бы всё правильно сделал

```
     .486                      ; create 32 bit code
      .model flat, stdcall      ; 32 bit memory model
      option casemap :none      ; case sensitive

      include \masm32\include\windows.inc
      include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
      include \masm32\include\gdi32.inc
      include \masm32\include\user32.inc
      include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
      include \masm32\include\Comctl32.inc
      include \masm32\include\comdlg32.inc
      include \masm32\include\shell32.inc
      include \masm32\include\oleaut32.inc
      include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
      include \masm32\include\dialogs.inc
      include \masm32\macros\macros.asm

      includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\gdi32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\Comctl32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\comdlg32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\shell32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\oleaut32.lib
      includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
     Main   PROTO  

.data?
hIcon           Dd ?
hBrush         Dd ?
hCursor       Dd ?
hImage        Dd ?
hInstance    Dd ?


.code

start:

      call Main
      invoke ExitProcess,eax

Main proc
 mov hInstance, FUNC(GetModuleHandle,NULL) 
  mov    hIcon, FUNC(LoadIcon, hInstance, 100)
  mov    hCursor, FUNC(LoadCursor,NULL,IDC_ARROW)
  mov    hBrush, FUNC(GetSysColorBrush, COLOR_APPWORKSPACE)

        invoke CreateWindowEx,WS_EX_TOPMOST,
                            chr$("my window"),
                            NULL,
                            WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE or TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS or \
                            TBSTYLE_FLAT or TBSTYLE_LIST or \
                            TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT,
                            0,0,500,20,
                            NULL,NULL,
                            hInstance,NULL

                            ret
Main endp
End start
```

Comment: CreateWindow и сразу после него ExitProcess - довольно странная программа, если вы ожидаете появления окна...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не появляется потому что что надо зарегистрировать класс окна, потом вызвать `CreateWindowEx`, потом запустить цикл обработки оконных сообщений.
Читайте msdn, там должны быть примеры.

Если нужно просто показать окно - то проще использовать `DialogBoxParam`, тогда достаточно одного вызова функции:

```
start:
  invoke DialogBoxParam, 0, chr$("my_dialog"), 0, DialogFunc, 0
  invoke ExitProcess, eax
```